# como hago para multplicar un vector por un numero cualquiera en la posicion i y guardarlo en otro vector

Tags: python

`factura[i] = Consumo[i]*700`
este operación de me da 0 no se porque igual que todas
este es el codigo completo

```
rep = 2
Usuario = [int() for ind0 in range(rep)] 
Cog = [int() for ind0 in range(rep)] 
Est = [int() for ind0 in range(rep)] 
Consumo = [int() for ind0 in range(rep)] 
factura = [int() for ind0 in range(rep)] 
for i in range (rep):
  print ("ingrese los datos de los usuarios",i+1 )
  Usuario[i] = str(input(print("Ingrese su nombre: ")))
  Cog[i] = int(str(input(print("ingrese su codigo: "))))
  Est[i] = int(str(input(print("Ingrese su estrato: "))))
  Consumo[i] = int(str(input(print("ingrese su consumo: "))))
  if Est  == 1:
    factura[i] = Consumo[i]*700
  elif Est  == 2:
    factura[i] = Consumo[i]*840
  elif Est  == 3:
    factura[i] = Consumo[i]*1100
  elif Est  == 4:
    factura[i] = Consumo[i]*1350
  elif Est  == 5:
    factura[i] = Consumo[i]*1800
  elif Est  == 6:
    factura[i] = Consumo[i]*2120
   
for i in range (rep):
    print("Mostrando los datos de los usuarios", i+1 )
    print("Nombre:", Usuario[i] )
    print("Su estracto es:", Est[i] )
    print("Su consumo es:", Consumo[i] )
    print ("Su factura es de:",factura[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

El error esta en `Est == 1`. `Est` es una lista, y nunca será igual a un valor entero. Es comparar peras con manzanas.

El código que muestras no es pitónico. Por de pronto, en Python manejas listas que crecen, no listas preasignadas. La razón es que una lista que crece se adapta a cualquier tamaño de problema. Por tanto, simplifico la inicialización de las variables:

```
rep = 2
Usuario = []
Cog = []
Est = []
Consumo = []
factura = []
```

Toda esa serie de `if` para calcular la facturación son una lata. La manera de simplificarlos es poner los factores en una lista y usar el estrato como indice para extraer el factor. El estrato comienza en 1:

```
factores = [0, 700, 840, 1100, 1350, 1800, 2120]
```

Luego sólo me queda ir pidiendo un dato tras otro.

```
for i in range(rep):
    print("ingrese los datos de los usuarios", i + 1)

    Usuario.append(input("Ingrese su nombre: "))
    Cog.append(int(input("ingrese su codigo: ")))
    Est.append(int(input("Ingrese su estrato: ")))
    Consumo.append(int(input("ingrese su consumo: ")))

    factura.append(Consumo[-1] * factores[Est[-1]])
```

El `input()` recibe como parámetro un texto a desplegar; no necesitas hacer `input(print(msg))`; basta con `input(msg)`.

Tampoco necesitas hacer `str(input())`, ya que `input()` simpre devuelve un string.

Como las listas crecen, ahora los nuevos datos se incorporan con `append()`.

Nota: En estricto rigor debería usar un `while True:` para incorporar cualquier cantidad de datos, más la detección de un valor centinela para salir del ciclo. Queda de tarea.

#### Demo

```
rep = 2
Usuario = []
Cog = []
Est = []
Consumo = []
factura = []
factores = [0, 700, 840, 1100, 1350, 1800, 2120]
for i in range(rep):
    print("ingrese los datos de los usuarios", i + 1)

    Usuario.append(input("Ingrese su nombre: "))
    Cog.append(int(input("ingrese su codigo: ")))
    Est.append(int(input("Ingrese su estrato: ")))
    Consumo.append(int(input("ingrese su consumo: ")))

    factura.append(Consumo[-1] * factores[Est[-1]])

for i in range(rep):
    print("Mostrando los datos de los usuarios", i + 1)
    print("Nombre:", Usuario[i])
    print("Su estracto es:", Est[i])
    print("Su consumo es:", Consumo[i])
    print("Su factura es de:", factura[i])
```

produce:

```
ingrese los datos de los usuarios 1
Ingrese su nombre: juan
ingrese su codigo: 1010
Ingrese su estrato: 1
ingrese su consumo: 100
ingrese los datos de los usuarios 2
Ingrese su nombre: raul
ingrese su codigo: 1011
Ingrese su estrato: 2
ingrese su consumo: 200
Mostrando los datos de los usuarios 1
Nombre: juan
Su estracto es: 1
Su consumo es: 100
Su factura es de: 70000
Mostrando los datos de los usuarios 2
Nombre: raul
Su estracto es: 2
Su consumo es: 200
Su factura es de: 168000
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

No puedo probarlo, pero de primeras haces una lista con los Est, y en el if comparas la lista con un número, creo que deberías usar:

```
if Est[i] == num:
```

Edito: a mayores, saca los str de los input, pasa únicamente a Int, puede que eso también tenga que ver en función de los valores que pongas, ojo, si quieres consumos con decimales debes usar float

Comment: Las respuestas deben llevar código que demuestra su funcionamiento.